# Selenium Webdriver Error Unknown strategy class

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to use Selenium to test my application. I wrote the initial tests using the Selenium IDE but, when I converted the IDE tests to Selenium Webdriver tests I got errors for about half of my code! So I'm going through each of the errors trying to get the code to work.

The error I'm getting in Web Driver is

> ERROR: Caught exception [Error: unknown strategy [class] for locator [class=x-tool-close]]

In Selenium IDE it had simply been Command `Click` and target `class=x-tool-close`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since I posted this question so I cannot be sure if I am addressing what the problem was exactly, but with that said the following is what I use for the command I mentioned above.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@class,'x-tool-close')]")).click();`

The structure of this command is very basic. Since the id of my elements are dynamic I search by xpath. Inside the quotation marks we have said xpath. We are searching for an 'img' element whose class attribute contains 'x-tool-close'. Then we are executing the selenium webdriver command click upon that element.

Comment: Why didn't you update your question instead of posting your update as an answer?

Comment: I believe your problem is that `img` is not a clickable web element. You need to refine your Xpath to obtain the clickable element (like "icon") that uses the image you want to "click"